# Get feedback from custom rqt gui interaction made with C++

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to make a GUI for a project.
The idea behind this is, that there are a view buttons and multiple text inputs.
Dependent on what button the user pressed, an action will be taken, with the text input values.
I use the rqt software frame and C++ program language to make a plugin.
My system is a ubuntu 16.04LTS with ROS kinetic.

I followed the tutorial steps from http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20C%2B%2B%20Plugin and the plugin is show-able in the rqt menu.
I can open it wen roscore is active, with *rqt* command in the terminal.

The problem i got is, i don't know how to get a reaction from the buttons.
I tried to make a function with the name **on_ButtonA_clicked()** (same type of function used in Qt program), but nothing happened.
I looked  at the examples linked in the rqt tutorials wiki page, but i that does not give me a clear solution.

Does anyone know how to make a function that reaction of a button press from the GUI or something comparable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310704/get-feedback-from-custom-rqt-gui-interaction-made-with-c++/) by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found my problem
I did not use connect, signal and slot command.

To connect a button interaction with C++ a connection signal and slot command is required.
Something like **connect(ui_.button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Load_object()));**.
The connection part connect the button with the action, signal set the type of trigger (this example it is a action wen clicked) and slot select the function, that will be activated.

---

Originally posted by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) with karma: 15 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0